# Calculations are either 1 more or 1 less decimal

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

I have this dialog that allows a user to edit a price. Now you can enter a cost price and it'll work out the wholesale and the retail price or you can enter the wholesale price and it will work out the retail and cost price or you can enter a retail price price and it'll work out the wholesale and cost price. I have been using 496.38 as my cost price so if I enter that value into my cost price field, it shows my wholesale to be 684.05 and my retail price to be 170.27.  if enter a whole price of 684.05, it shows my cost price to be 496.38 and retail price to be 170.27 which is all good and right. the issue is if I enter into the retail field first, and I enter 170.27, cost price becomes 496.37 and whole becomes 684.04 and the cost is 496.37.

My functions

```
    private decimal CostPrice
    {
        get =>  SelectedItem.Cost;
        set
        {
            SelectedItem.Cost = value;
            SelectedItem.WholesalePrice = Math.Round(((((decimal)SelectedItem.Cost+(decimal)SelectedItem.Transport+(decimal)SelectedItem.RoyaltyMarket+((decimal)SelectedItem.DelStrand))/(1-(decimal)SelectedItem.Margin)*(1+(decimal)SelectedItem.AdjPercentage))+(decimal)SelectedItem.Levy),2); // Calculate and set the wholesale price
            SelectedItem.RecRetailPrice =Math.Round((((decimal)SelectedItem.WholesalePrice / (1m - 0.23m)) * (100m + 15m) / 100m  ) / (SelectedItem.StockUom) , 2); 
            /*CalculateRetailPrice(SelectedItem.WholesalePrice);*/ // Calculate and set the retail price
        }
    }
    private decimal WholesalePrice
    {
        get => SelectedItem.WholesalePrice;
        set
        {
            SelectedItem.WholesalePrice = value;
            SelectedItem.RecRetailPrice = Math.Round((((decimal)SelectedItem.WholesalePrice/(1m-0.23m))*(100+15)/100)/SelectedItem.StockUom,2);
            SelectedItem.Cost= Math.Round((((decimal)SelectedItem.WholesalePrice-(decimal)SelectedItem.Levy)/(1+(decimal)SelectedItem.AdjPercentage))*(1-(decimal)SelectedItem.Margin)-(decimal)SelectedItem.Transport-(decimal)SelectedItem.RoyaltyMarket-(decimal)SelectedItem.DelStrand,2);

        }

    }


    private decimal RecRetailPrice
    {
        get => SelectedItem.RecRetailPrice;
        set
        {
            SelectedItem.RecRetailPrice = value;
            SelectedItem.WholesalePrice =Math.Round((((decimal)SelectedItem.RecRetailPrice * (1m - 0.23m))/(100+15)*100)*SelectedItem.StockUom,2);
            SelectedItem.Cost = Math.Round((((SelectedItem.WholesalePrice - (decimal)SelectedItem.Levy) / (1m + (decimal)SelectedItem.AdjPercentage)) * (1m - (decimal)SelectedItem.Margin)) - (decimal)SelectedItem.Transport - (decimal)SelectedItem.RoyaltyMarket - (decimal)SelectedItem.DelStrand,2);
        }
    }
```

I tried to remove the Math.Round and and alter the calculations in any combination possible but no result

Comment: FWIW This does not look like a well written set of getter/setters in a model as it appears to be overreaching and setting property values in another model (`SelectedItem.`which is not included in this code set)

Comment: And both is correct, isn't it? If you have 24.8914% tax, then 648.04*tax is 170.267 and you need to ruond up and 648.05*tax is 170.269 and you round up to the same value. So for the backward calculation, you can't know whether the origin was 648.04 or 684.05

Comment: `(1m - 0.23m)`  WHY? why not just `0.77m` so `(1m - 0.23m))/(100+15)*100)` is just `(0.77m))/(115)*100)` etc.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: why not? If 23% is in the task description (the requirements), then it's clear where the number comes from, whereas 77% is a magic number which you need to think about.

Comment: FWIW they are both "magic numbers" as it currently stands - perhaps put some named private constants/variables in the class - lots of opinion related options;

Comment: Do not do math with rounded values as the error is going to accumulate very fast. Keep the true values in the variables for the math, and _only apply rounding when you display the values_.

Comment: What is the type of `SelectedItem`? Show the definition because the calculations should definitely be done inside the class and not under some other class.

Comment: Do you know that `x/a*b` equals to `(x*b)/a` and not `x/(a*b)`. It seems you have a mix of multiplications and divisions and it is not clear what is actually on the numerator and what is in the denominator. Also when you have repeated similar calculations it is time ti create functions for them.

Answer (score 0):

All your calculations boil down to two functions and their inverses

```
private decimal GetWholesaleFromRetail(decimal amount)
{
    return amount * (decimal)( (1 - 0.23f) / (1 + 0.15f) * StockUom);
}

private decimal GetRetailFromWholesale(decimal amount)
{
    return amount / (decimal)( (1 - 0.23f) / (1 + 0.15f) * StockUom);
}

private decimal GetCostFromWholesale(decimal amount)
{
    return (amount - Levy) / (decimal)((1 + AdjPercentage) * (1 - Margin)) - Transport - RoyaltyMarket - DelStrand;
}

private decimal GetWholesaleFromCost(decimal amount)
{
    return ((amount + Transport + RoyaltyMarket + DelStrand) / (decimal)((1 - Margin) * (1 + AdjPercentage))) + Levy;
}
```

But I am convinced there is a math error here, causing the result to be inconsistent.

Like if you made the round trip `[Retail]->[Wholesale]->[Retail]` would you end up with the same number?

Also for `[Wholesale]->[Cost]->[Wholesale]`

It is impossible to test with actual numbers because you have not given all the dependent values in the post.

---

I also recommend creating a class that contains all the calculations to be used as follows in your code:

```
Item SelectedItem = new Item(
    margin: 0.1f,
    adjPercentage: 0.05f,
    stockUom: 0.03f,
    levy: 30m,
    transport: 50m,
    royaltyMarket: 5m,
    delStrand: 4m);

SelectedItem.Cost = 1000m;

Console.WriteLine($"     Cost = {SelectedItem.Cost:m2}");
Console.WriteLine($"Wholesale = {SelectedItem.WholesalePrice:m2}");
Console.WriteLine($"   Retail = {SelectedItem.RecRetailPrice:m2}");
```

and the class `Item` will contain all the values needed, and the varying amounts (cost,wholesale,retail) as parameters.

```
public class Item
{
    decimal _cost;
    decimal _wholesalePrice;
    decimal _recRetailPrice;

    public Item(float adjPercentage, float margin, decimal royaltyMarket, decimal transport, decimal delStrand, float stockUom, decimal levy)
    {
        AdjPercentage = adjPercentage;
        Margin = margin;
        RoyaltyMarket = royaltyMarket;
        Transport = transport;
        DelStrand = delStrand;
        StockUom = stockUom;
        Levy = levy;
    }

    public decimal Cost
    {
        get => _cost;
        set
        {
            _cost = value;
            _wholesalePrice = GetWholesaleFromCost(_cost);
            _recRetailPrice = GetRetailFromWholesale(_wholesalePrice);
        }
    }

    public decimal WholesalePrice
    {
        get => _wholesalePrice;
        set
        {
            _wholesalePrice = value;
            _recRetailPrice = GetRetailFromWholesale(_wholesalePrice);
            _cost = GetCostFromWholesale(_wholesalePrice);
        }
    }


    public decimal RecRetailPrice
    {
        get => _recRetailPrice;
        set
        {
            _recRetailPrice = value;
            _wholesalePrice = GetWholesaleFromRetail(_recRetailPrice);
            _cost = GetCostFromWholesale(_wholesalePrice);
        }
    }

    private decimal GetWholesaleFromRetail(decimal amount)
    {
        return amount * (decimal)( (1 - 0.23f) / (1 + 0.15f) * StockUom);
    }

    private decimal GetRetailFromWholesale(decimal amount)
    {
        return amount / (decimal)( (1 - 0.23f) / (1 + 0.15f) * StockUom);
    }

    private decimal GetCostFromWholesale(decimal amount)
    {
        return (amount - Levy) / (decimal)((1 + AdjPercentage) * (1 - Margin)) - Transport - RoyaltyMarket - DelStrand;
    }

    private decimal GetWholesaleFromCost(decimal amount)
    {
        return ((amount + Transport + RoyaltyMarket + DelStrand) / (decimal)((1 - Margin) * (1 + AdjPercentage))) + Levy;
    }

    public float AdjPercentage { get; }
    public float Margin { get; }
    public decimal RoyaltyMarket { get;  }
    public decimal Transport { get; }
    public decimal DelStrand { get; }
    public float StockUom { get; }
    public decimal Levy { get; }
}
```